# Using determinant of Jacobian to prove injectivity

Tags: determinant, problem-solving, inverse-function, jacobian

[image]

How would you go about to solve this?

I computed Det of the Jacobian at (1,1) and got that it is not equal to 0 so does that mean it is invertible and thus bijective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

1. $\;\bar{v}$ is continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of $(1,1)$.

   $\;\det(J_{\bar{v}}(1,1)) \ne 0$.

it follows, by the inverse function theorem, that $\bar{v}$ is injective in a neighborhood of the point $(1,1)$.

However, $\bar{v}$ is not injective on $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus \{(0,0)\}$, since, for example
$$\bar{v}\left(0,\sqrt{\pi/2}\right)=\bar{v}\left(0,-\sqrt{\pi/2}\right)$$

Comment: v  is injective in a neighborhood of the point (1,1)(1,1). Because of the fact that since detJv is not equal to 0 the function is bijective at (1,1)?

Comment: $v$ is locally injective since $v$ is continuosly differentiable at $(1,1)$the determinant of the Jacobian is nonzero. 
$\qquad$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem

Answer (score 2):

The Jacobian is invertible, hence $v$ is locally invertible at $(1,1)$. This excludes the fourth and the third answers. Now, you can see that $v$ is not invertible in $\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ because $$v(1,1) = v(-1,-1)$$ hence the answer is $(i)$.